# How to set cpu fan speed for Intel® skylake based cpu on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, fan, intel-core-i7

I [checked on how to manage cpu fan speed on Linux](https://askubuntu.com/q/22108) and unfortunately, none of the methods works. `sensors-detect` only detect `coretemp` which only allows to read temperature.

Additionally, `find /sys -iname \*wm\*` report nothing *(no pwm files)*.
My chipset is `Z170 express` with a Gigabyte motherboard.
I have no problem at setting the cpu fan speed on Windows®.

Looks like my hardware is too new to be fully supported by Linux *(even with the latest longterm kernel)*.
**But is there a way to bypass this *(I don’t know maybe the kernel module already exists)*** ?

Comment: The problem is the default configuration provided by my efi system can’t set the cpu fan to it’s maximum speed nor it’s minimal speed. Currently, the only way to do it is to boot on Windows®.

Comment: Having the exact same issue, same motherboard.

Answer (score 2):

Try loading the nct6775 kernel module.

```
$ sudo modprobe nct6775
$ sensors
nct6793-isa-0a20
Adapter: ISA adapter
[...]
fan1: ...
```

nct6775 may report some unreasonably high values for SYSTIN and CPUTIN ([issue #45](https://github.com/groeck/nct6775/issues/45)).

To run fan 2 at max speed (change hwmon4 as appropriate):

```
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon4/pwm2_enable # manual fan control
$ echo 255 | sudo tee /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon4/pwm2      # max speed
```

If it works, you can load nct6775 at boot:

```
$ echo nct6775 | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/nct6775.conf
```

Does your UEFI/BIOS let you control fan speed based on several temperature points? You can change those points instead of directly changing PWM values.

```
$ cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon4/pwm2_enable # 5 = "Smart Fan IV mode"
5

$ cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon4/pwm2_auto_point1_temp
40000

$ cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon4/pwm2_auto_point1_pwm
22
```

For details refer to the [nct6775 README](https://github.com/groeck/nct6775).

Currently suspend/resume resets the settings to the UEFI/BIOS defaults. Please monitor temperatures and be careful when controlling fan speeds.

Comment: Unfortunately, I got a`No such device`error when trying to insmod the module. So this can’t be this.